# socks4|5 proxy component

Tags: c#, proxy

Does anyone know .net component which support socks4 and socks5 proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Mentalis ProxySocket](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/class.qpx?id=9). It's free and has been around since 2002.